# After update Typo3 8.7.31 - no page tree in backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I updated my Typo3 project from Typo3 7.6 to 8.7.31

I installed all extensions in the newest version, which where installed before.

But the pagetree doesn't show up.

[Here are some infos the console prints out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1ayn.png)

Comment: in your screenshot is visible, that a lot of resources can't be loaded, but more information would be available in the 'network'  tab. especially if you inspect one of the failures (look for the returned data)

Comment: Ahhh... it was a caching problem. Now its walking perfectly.